# How can I decrease the amount of Confirmation Dialogues

Tags: fallout-4

> Are you sure you want to exit the crafting station?

Yes I am sure, there are literally no consequences for me exiting, I can just enter it again.

Fallout 4 asks for a lot of confirmation.
Exiting crafting stations, before scrapping items and several other places.
This really bugs me.
It bugged me in Skyrim and crafting wasn't as much a core part of gameplay as it is in the latest Fallout.

The worst is when it asked for confirmation on actions that have no consequences like leaving a workbench. To a lesser extent I am annoyed by things like asking if I am sure I want to Scrap this broken chair (Particularly after I have scrapped every other broken chair I have seen).

I am trying to work out how to turn it off.

I can't find anything in the ingame Options. I've only had a short look at the .ini config options but can't find anything there either.
I'm not sure if there are mods that can fix this.

One thing that makes it less annoying is that you can close them with <kbd>E</kbd> rather than <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But still annoying.

When scraping I end up two finger pressing <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> more or less at same time.

Comment: The negative consequence of leaving a station too early is having to go through the animations to leave it and get back in. The confirmation has saved me plenty of times.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no option in game or via the configuration files to reduce the quantity of or disable the confirmation dialogues.